# Mysql select statement contains where clause so unsuitable for insert into

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, where-clause

I'm very inexperienced. I've prepared a select statement which gives the information I need to populate a matches table. However it is not suitable because it contains a where clause. Is there a different way to use it, or how can I change it so that it is suitable for INSERT INTO.

The tables are as follows:-

### match_order

match_order_id||match_descrip||first_player||second_player
  1    1v2  1  2
  2    1v3  1  3
  3    2v3  2  3
  4    1v4  1  4
  5    2v4  2  4
  6    3v4  3  4

### entries

entry_id||round_id||league_id||box_id||box_position
1  1  1  1  1
2  1  1  1  2
3  1  1  1  3
4  1  2  1  4
5  1  2  1  2
6  1  2  1  1
7  1  2  1  1

### matches

match_id||round_id||league_id||box_id||match_order_id||player1||player2

I need to insert new rows every month for a new round of matches. League size, box size & positions change each month.

This is the statement which gives the correct rows.

```
SELECT e.round_id, e.league_id, e.box_id, mo.match_order_id, e.entry_id as player1, e1.entry_id as player2
FROM match_order mo
LEFT JOIN entries e ON mo.first_player = e.box_position
LEFT JOIN entries e1 ON mo.second_player = e1.box_position
WHERE e.round_id = e1.round_id AND e.league_id = e1.league_id AND e.box_id = e1.box_id
ORDER BY round_id, league_id, box_id, match_order_id
```

Any help & advise would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Can't you just add the `INSERT INTO matches(round_id, leage_id, box_id, match_order_id, player1, player2)` before your `SELECT`?  And probably remove the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `match_id` is an auto-increment column, you have the data for the other columns.  You can just add the `INSERT` statement before your `SELECT`.

```
INSERT INTO matches(round_id, leage_id, box_id, match_order_id, player1, player2)
SELECT e.round_id, e.league_id, e.box_id, mo.match_order_id, e.entry_id as player1, e1.entry_id as player2
FROM match_order mo
LEFT JOIN entries e ON mo.first_player = e.box_position
LEFT JOIN entries e1 ON mo.second_player = e1.box_position
WHERE e.round_id = e1.round_id AND e.league_id = e1.league_id AND e.box_id = e1.box_id
```

Comment: Many thanks, that was what I tried (obviously had an error somewhere) this time it worked perfectly. I got caught up trying to think of another way & googling too many things.